# How can i detect if a Card or a RecyclerView's item is selected?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, cardview, long-press

i'm new to Android and i'm working on a University project, an app to take notes. I can add and delete note, but i would like to implement a classic way to delete an item: long press on it and delete it with dialogs or whatever.

This is what i have: [Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIdt2.png)

I tried to click for a few seconds on the cards/notes (they are in a recycle view nested in a coordinator layout) and i saw that a background visual effect is displayed, so i think that something is already implemented.

Let me know if you need XML layout implementation or something else to answer. Thanks! :)

**EDIT**
requested code

```
CardView cardView = findViewById(R.id.cardId);
    cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "long click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

**XML Declaration of the cardview**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/touch_layout"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/cardStyle"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                tools:text="title"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/showText"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/showText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_leftarrow" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                tools:text="@string/date" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                tools:text="message..." />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use long click listener easy on recylerview

```
 itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                   Log.v("LongClick: "+"LongClick");
                    return true;// returning true instead of false, works for me
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the background is the nativen effect applied on some ItemViews by Android. For registering clicks, follow these steps:

1. Create the layout in the XML and assign an ID to it.

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/timestamp"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
   ```
2. Declare and define the view (TextView in this case) by using the assigned ID:

   ```
   TextView messageText;
   messageText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
   ```
3. Attach Listener to register clicks:

   ```
   messageText.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onLongClick(View view){
       // Do what you want here.
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Oh, i didn't see that listener on the documentation. I think it should work, but when i try to link the Cardview to the listener through the specific id i get a NullPointerException on calling the OnLongClickListener because the object is Null.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct ID and the scope, it'll be great if you can share the code.

Comment: Where is this CardView cardView ... code? Share the complete file

Comment: If you mean the Cardview XML file it's in now. If it's important, i use it in a RecyclerView with a RecyclerView adapter